# Etherpad disconnects when collaborate with multiple users

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, vuejs2, etherpad

Inside a Vue component, I run multiple instances of [Etherpad](https://etherpad.org/) editor which are embedded in iframes. Below is an example of that component-

`Etherpad.vue (A page component)`

```
<div>
  <iframe src="https://mydomain.in/p/1505-g4Q?token=uuid&userName=jo&userColor=%23ffc7c7&rtl=false&lang=en"></iframe>
  <iframe src="https://mydomain.in/p/1506-g4Q?token=uuid&userName=jo&userColor=%23ffc7c7&rtl=false&lang=en"></iframe>
  <iframe src="https://mydomain.in/p/1507-g4Q?token=uuid&userName=jo&userColor=%23ffc7c7&rtl=false&lang=en"></iframe>
</div>
```

Now, I prepare a URL for this page suppose its, `https://mydomain.in/etherpad/collaborate` and share it with others to collaborate on this page. Each user who has access to this URL can type inside these three editors.

## The issue

If only a single user is collaborating on this page, things are fine. As soon as other users started working on it, each user is having the following popup of disconnection-

[image]

And once a user clicks **force reconnects**, it appears on the other user's side which is resultant to allow only one user to type at a time.

## Environment

**vue:** 2.6.11
**node :** 13.14.0"
**Etherpad version:** 1.8.16,
**Web server:** Nginx
**Browser**: Chrome
**Authentication:** Custom JWT verification (can see in iframe URLs)
**Etherpad database type:** postgress (database is hosted on a separate machine)

- Etherpad client and Vue are being served on the same domain to avoid the cross-domain
  cookies, and cross-domain embedding issues.
- I am serving Etherpad behind Nginx reverse proxy. On the root
  path `('/')` I serve the Vue application and on `/p/` path requests,
  I pass them to the Etherpad node server.

## Things I tried to debug

- Tested locally, one user in Firefox and another in Chrome, working fine.
- Tested with two users with different IP addresses, giving a disconnection popup.
- Some answers say to look into the settings to alter the connection limit but didn't mention which settings.
- For some users, this issue occurs when pasting a long text but for me, it's happening even when typing a single sentence.

Any help to suggest where to debug or which settings to change even in code or at server configuration would be great.

Comment: Not an answer, but rather direction for further debug - check browser console (Ctrl-Shift-C in Chrome) and network events when this disconnection is happening. This may give more clues to what is going on.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I tried it already but couldn't find any relevant error message. Still, I'll give it one more try.